# Scope of Variables in Java -- issue

Tags: java

Okay so I'm having a problem with scope of an object. I'm using Jsoup right now and here's the code:

```
//Website is /001.shtml, so adding count to the string wouldn't work. 
//This is why I have the ifs

if (count < 10)
{
 Document site = Jsoup.connect(url + "00" + count).get();
}
else if (count < 100)
{
  Document site = Jsoup.connect(url + "0" + count + ".shtml").get();
}
else
{
  Document site = Jsoup.connect(url + count + ".shtml").get();
}
```

Okay so I create the Document object called 
site, and I need to add a certain amount of zeros because of how the person made the website, no problem. However when I try to use site.select(anything), I can't because the object was defined in the if construct.

Also, I can not initialize it outside the if, it does not work because I get a duplicate error thrown. Please tell me there is a fix for this because I have searched and searched to no avail, and I don't want to have to put the rest of the program 3 times into different ifs...

Comment: You should be using String formatter.  like this would make the input 3 digits: String.format("%03d", numberValueHere)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work?"  Please provide an error message and include a minimal program that triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `site` outside the `if..else` blocks:

```
Document site;
if (count < 10){
    site = Jsoup.connect(url + "00" + count).get();
} else if (count < 100) {
    site = Jsoup.connect(url + "0" + count + ".shtml").get();
} else {
    site = Jsoup.connect(url + count + ".shtml").get();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use nested ternary operators:

```
Document site = Jsoup.connect(
        count < 10  ? url + "00" + count
      : count < 100 ? url + "0" + count + ".shtml"
      :               url + count + ".shtml"
    ).get();
```

If I'm correct that your code has a bug and the `count < 10` case is missing `+ ".shtml"`, then the best solution is:

```
Document site = Jsoup.connect(url + String.format("%03d.shtml", count)).get();
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it does not work due to duplicate of site.

Comment: @RobertStanton - What duplicate of site? Note that in my code I've eliminated the type name when `site` is used inside the `if` blocks.

Comment: +1 for not assigning `null` in the declaration, so the compiler will warn you if you forget to properly initialize it before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration outside the `if` else if chain, like

```
Document site = null;
if (count < 10) { 
  site = Jsoup.connect(url + "00" + count + ".shtml").get(); // was missing shtml.
} else if (count < 100) {
  site = Jsoup.connect(url + "0" + count + ".shtml").get();
} else {
  site = Jsoup.connect(url + count + ".shtml").get();
}
```

Or you might build the url and then connect once like,

```
String urlStr = url + String.format("%03d", count) + ".shtml";
Document site = Jsoup.connect(urlStr).get();
```

Comment: I have already tried that, unfortunately it does not work and I can't figure out why.